# html5 localStorage not setting with click function

Tags: jquery, html

I can't set localStorage through a .click function on a div class.

The following code doesn't work.

```
<div class="time"></div>

$(".time").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("time", "0.6");
});
```

How do I get this to work?

### FIXED (UPDATE)

I got it to work.
I grabbed the parent class of "time" in my code which is "main". That allowed me to set the localStorage.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="time"></div>
</div>

$(".main").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem("time", "0.6");
});
```

Thanks,
Timothy

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) - it will help us to help you

Comment: How do you know it is not storing the key pair? Are you getting an error or anything?

Where is the code where you retrieve the session var?

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you guys!  I grabbed the parent class of "time" which is "main". That allowed me to set the localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:
Clicking the div outputs .6 to the console - so it is indeed working. I would check your getter syntax.

**JS**

```
$(".time").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("time", "0.6");
    var data = localStorage.getItem("time");
    console.log(data);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.time{
  padding:20px 40px;
  background-color:#000;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="time">Click Me</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6jkcvhnz/)

Comment: Thank you @Korgrue. This works too!